# The sample distribution (pdf) of the sample mean retrieved from gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

Is it true that the sample distribution (pdf) of the mean where sample is of size n retrieved from a gamma distribution with shape a and scale b is given by

$f_{\bar{X}}(x)=\frac{n(nx)^{na-1}e^{-nx/b}}{\Gamma(na)b^{an}}$ ?

If not, what is the correct distribution for the sample mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is a random sample drawn from a gamma distribution with shape $a$ and scale $b$, then their sum $T = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ is also gamma with the same scale but with shape $an$.  Then the distribution of the sample mean is given by a simple monotone transformation:  $\bar X = T/n$ has density $$f_{\bar X}(x) = n f_T(nx),$$ which of course is gamma with shape $an$ and scale $b/n$.  This makes sense because the expectation of a single observation is $\operatorname{E}[X_i] = ab$; the expectation of their sum must then be $\operatorname{E}[T] = abn$; and the expectation of the sample mean must be the same as that for a single observation:  $$\operatorname{E}[\bar X] = (an)(b/n) = ab.$$  Yet we require the variance of the sample mean to be a decreasing function of the sample size $n$, which is indeed the case:  $$\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = ab^2,$$ but $$\operatorname{Var}[\bar X] = (an)(b/n)^2 = \frac{ab^2}{n} \le ab^2$$ for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: For those who still wonder, the answer was yes.